# OpenMP doesn't run parallel with JNI

Tags: java, c++, parallel-processing, java-native-interface, openmp

I have a c++ code that uses openMP to run in parallel.

```
void f(){
omp_set_num_threads(3);
#pragma omp parallel 
{
if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0 ){

      // do task 1   

}else if (omp_get_thread_num() == 1){

     //do task 2

}else if (omp_get_thread_num() == 2){

     //do task 3
}}
```

I use SWIG JNI to create a dll and call this code from Java.

```
System.loadLibrary("model");
model.f();
```

It runs in serial mode. When I compile the code directly with c++ and run in command line, it runs parallel.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you call the same binary for both command-line and JNI?  Or do you compile different binaries, an executable for command-line and a library for JNI?

Comment: for JNI, I create a dll using swig and g++, and then load the dll it in Java. I don't create a binary. 

    `swig -c++ -java model.i'
    `g++ -c model.cpp model_wrap.cxx -I ...' 
    `g++ -shared model.o model_wrap.o  -o model.dll  -I ... -L ... and some libraries'

But for direct c++ use, I create a binary using g++ compiler and use that.

    `g++ model.cpp -o model.exe -I ... -L ... and libraries`

Comment: Assuming g++ and OpenMP are similar to Linux usage, what happens in your binary if you compile to a `.o` file using the `-fopenmp` argument to `g++`, but leave off `-fopenmp` during the link step?  I suspect the OpenMP library isn't getting loaded by the JVM.  But I've never used OpenMP on Windows....

Comment: You are right Andrew, openMP wasn't getting loaded because I didn't have -fopenmp in one of my commands, that fixed it. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, your current problem was answered by @Andrew Henle in the comments: you need to use `-fopenmp` during both the compilation and linking steps.

However, I wanted to expand and say that your code as-is presents a textbook case of when to use OpenMP `sections`. You should change your code to take advantage of these semantics:

```
void f() {
    omp_set_num_threads(3);
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            // do task 1   
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            //do task 2
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            //do task 3
        }
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of (a) becoming serial code when you do not compile with OpenMP support, one of the original tenets of OpenMP; and (b) Easily allowing for an extension for more `section`s and/or more threads. OpenMP handles all load balancing for you if you have more `section`s than threads.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful indeed!